Raw sensor value to Celsius temperature with DJI SDK?
I have some R-JPEG captured with a drone DJI Mavic 3T, and I have to extract thermal information from it.
I've been reading documentation from ExifTool and from DJI SDK, and after some experiments I've managed to extract some forms of temperature information.
Approach 1:
I tried thermal_parser, and I could correctly plot the images I'm working with.
import numpy as np
from thermal_parser import Thermal

thermal = Thermal(dtype=np.float32)
temperature = thermal.parse(filepath_image='./DJI_blablablabla_.JPG')

plt.imshow(temperature, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')

# Add colorbar to indicate temperature values
plt.colorbar(label='Temperature')

# Set the title and labels
plt.title('Temperature Heatmap')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

However, when analysing the array of temperatures, I realised that the values are a little skewed, because when I process the thermography with DJI SKI, one of the lines of the output says that the array of temperatures goes from 12º to 38º, when thermal_parser says that they go from 9º to 41º
Approach 2: With DJI SDK
I was hoping I could run dji_sdk with Python using subprocess and get a (512, 640, 1) array containing the temperature (in ºC) detected on each pixel. However, I've only managed to produce raw files as outputs which contains things such as the RGB values to plot a coloured thermography.
# Example
> .\dji_irp.exe -s .\DJI_blablabla.JPG -a process -o process.raw -p iron_red
# process.raw can be read as a binary file and reshaped as (512, 640, 3)
# which can be then plotted as an image

When using dji_irp with measure and extract option, I get a 655360 elements long array as output (which is, coincidentally, the result of multiplying 512x640x2), but I don't know what to do with this output. I've plotted it as an image, which shows me a streched, partially overlapped with itself, version of the input image.
One of my key concerns is, is it possible to produce such an output? As in, to get a 2D matrix with the temperature of each pixel using DJI SDK?
Approach 3: With Exif Tool
After reading some documentation, I found a post (thanks Chris Willey for your contributions) about extracting ThermalData directly from the metadata using exiftool, numpy and subprocess.
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import tifffile as tiff

temps = subprocess.check_output(['exiftool', '-b', '-ThermalData', './DJI_blablablabl.JPG'])
temp_data = np.frombuffer(temps, dtype=np.int16)
new_temp = np.reshape(temp_data, (512,640))  # reshape the array based on image dimensions
tiff.imwrite('output.tif', new_temp)

However, here I obtain the raw data from the sensor, which is a list of values such as 19464, 19464, 19464, ..., 18676, 18676, 18652. I'd like to now if there is a way to convert them to ºC with any "official" tools, because I found this snippet (from pierotofy) which seems to work perfectly fine to do this conversion, but I'd like to know if there is a more orthodoxe way to accomplish it.
raw = np.array(Image.frombytes('I;16L', (640, 512), a), np.int16)
celsius = np.right_shift(raw, 2).astype(np.float32)
celsius *= 0.0625
celsius -= 273.15
#celsius is far more adjusted to the real temperatures


why do you shift? is it just 14 bits? -- the shift is pointless. you can fold that into the factor (0.0625 = 1/16, 1/64 = 0.015625)

@ChristophRackwitz the developer of that snippet didn't give any explanation and I'm not versed enough in this matter to know why (hence the reason to try to find help here), I just know those operations actually help me retrieve temperature values which look like the right ones

What do you mean by "fold that into the factor"? @ChristophRackwitz
